# Remove White Space above header image

Tags: html, css

I've looked at various "white space" issues, but none seem to work. I am using normalize.css. The only solution I have found is doing something like this:

```
.parallaxImage {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

But I doubt this is really the best way to do it. I doubt it's responsive and completely cross-browser compatible. Is there any alternative solution that works? Here's the codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZNovx

Comment: Do you use reset or normalizer or atleast some basic style for margins/padding etc?

Comment: Yeah, I use normalize (i edited my answer to mention that), but I got it figured out :-)

Comment: Looks like normalizer does bad job :P I have custom one for these kind of things. Saves a lot of time. Tried normalizer did not like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top margin is coming from the `<h2>` inside the parallaxImage div.

```
h2 {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Will resolve the issue.

Comment: Ahhh Shoot. Such a simple fix. I just realized how to figure this out in the future. I could have just opened up the dev tools and inspected the area. Thank you! I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes.